# How to reload fetchedResultsController on viewWillAppear?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

How to reload fetchedResultsController on viewWillAppear? because I want to reload the table view and data after I dismiss a pop out view controller.

This fetch controller seem only run when the view is load because It keep the old data. How to run or refresh the fetch controller when the view is appear?

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Record> {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Record> = Record.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
    let accBtn = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "BtnName") as! String
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "accountbook" , "\(accBtn)")
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: "createdAt", cacheName: nil)
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}

var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Record>? = nil

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .update:
        self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as! DashboardCell, withRecordItem: anObject as! Record)
    case .move:
        tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: I've got the same problem... any solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

If your ViewController is in memory when you change the data in the managed object context, the fetched result controller delegates should  work.

In your current implementation, you are updating the tableview when each change is made and its not always advisable to do it. I guess you need to digress and implement only `didChangeContent` and `reloadData` on it

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I tried this. after I dismiss the pop vc, the table is refresh but the list is something wrong (some data not display) and when I select the cell, I got this error `'cannot access fetched objects before -performFetch:'`

Comment: @WanJern: Have you removed all the other delegate methods?

Comment: Do you mean I have to removed - `controllerWillChangeContent, didChange section & anObject` ? but I need it to update my UI and group the same date item in a section.. @Puneet Sharma

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Calling reloadData on tableView On didChangeContent, will do all the required changes.

Comment: Ok, I tried to removed it but its still display old data after I dismiss the pop out vc...